# UITest XCUIElementQuery missing elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitest

```
//Helper
class UITest: XCTestCase {
    final func setInitalCredentials() {
        print("\(app.textFields.count)") <-- prints (1)
        let loginTextField = app.textFields["LoginTextField"] <-- is found
        loginTextField.tap()
        let deleteKey = app.keys["delete"]
        let _ = deleteKey.waitForExistence(timeout: 2)
        deleteKey.press(forDuration: 2)
        loginTextField.typeText("login")

        let passwordTextField = app.textFields["PasswordTextField"] <- is not
        passwordTextField.tap()
        let _ = deleteKey.waitForExistence(timeout: 2)
        deleteKey.press(forDuration: 2)
        passwordTextField.typeText("password")
    }

    var app: XCUIApplication!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        app.launchArguments.append("--uitesting")
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        app.terminate()
        super.tearDown()
        app.launch()
    }
}

//Actual test
class UILoginViewTest: UITest {

    func testLogin() {
        setInitalCredentials()
        let loginButton = app.buttons["Connect"]
        loginButton.tap()
        let applicationRootView = app.otherElements["QuotesViewController"]
        let _ = applicationRootView.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
        XCTAssert(applicationRootView.exists)
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Why is second `UITextField` not found? I am sure all IDs are set, I cannot even access it via placeholder or text, cause `XCUIElementQuery` tells I have only 1 `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app` has `secureTextFields`, which contains any `UITextFields' with secure text entering.